# Grunt requirejs nested dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

I have a config file with all path and shim data :

```
require.config({

paths : {

    'jquery'                : 'libs/jquery-1.10.2.min',
    'backbone'              : 'libs/backbone-min',
    'underscore'            : 'libs/underscore-min',
    'layer'                 : 'src/views/base/LayerView'
    ...
},


shim : {

    'backbone': {

        deps    : ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports : 'Backbone'
    },
    'underscore' : {

        exports : '_'
    },
  }
});
```

And a main file as app starting point:

```
require(['./config'], function (config) {

require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'src/router/PageRouter'], function($, _, Backbone, PageRouter) {

    new PageRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
   });
});
```

if I run the grunt requirejs task, it doesn't include the dependencies:

```
        options: {

            baseUrl             : '_js',
            name                : "src/main",
            mainConfigFile      : basePath + '_js/src/main.js',
            out                 : basePath + '_js/min/script.min.js',
            normalizeDirDefines : 'all'
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is to enable [findNestedDependencies](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L339) flag.

you might want to get rid of nested dependencies, see [seperating config file](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module), and [deps config](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L442) and [explanation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

Comment: findNestedDependencies does not work :
>> Tracing dependencies for: src/main
>> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>> /_js/jquery.js'
>> In module tree:
>>     src/main
Seems like it doesn't include / trace the config